# Sql job when certain things happen

Tags: sql, sql-server

lets say I have the table below

**Table User**

```
UserId int
Username varchar(50)
```

**Table History**

```
ID int
WhoWasAdded varchar(50)
```

The SQl Job must insert a row into Table History every time a new user is added to Table User
`WhoWasAdded` comes from `Username`

Comment: Google for SQL Server after insert trigger, you can find plenty of examples

Comment: This does not require a SQL job. What you want is an `AFTER INSERT` trigger.

Comment: *Or* this should be handled in the Porcedure you use to `INSERT` the data into the User table.

Comment: Okay Got it thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample insert trigger code...

```
CREATE TABLE User
(
  [NAME] NVARCHAR(50)
)
GO

CREATE TABLE History
(
  [name] NVARCHAR(50)
)
GO

CREATE TRIGGER tblUpdateTrigger ON User
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO History ([name])
  SELECT T.[name]
  FROM  user T
  INNER JOIN inserted i ON T.[name]=I.[name] 
END
GO
```